# How to specify environment variable for a "Shell Script" run configuration in PyCharm?

Tags: python, bash, pycharm, environment-variables

My flask app gets its DB credentials from an environment variable. I run it locally by running a small bash file `run.sh` that just calls `flask run` with a few options.

I'd like to be able to have both a 'dev' and 'prod' run configurations in PyCharm, calling this same bash script with a different `PG_URL` env variable (to tell it to connect to either a local or remote staging / prod DB). I don't want to put the credentials in git but am okay having them in a PyCharm run configuration.

Unfortunately when editing run configurations for a shell script there is no place to specify environment variables (while that option is here for a python script), so I'm not sure how to set this up. This seems like a fairly basic feature, am I missing something obvious? How do I set this up?

[image: Run/Debug Configurations window in PyCharm]

Answer (score 1):

You can include the variables in the command to run in the config, for example:

```
PG_URL=<url> bash run.sh
```

Comment: This doesn't work because the configuration asks for a script path, not a command to run

Comment: What type of run config is this? From my experience IntelliJ doesn't directly support bash run configs. Maybe a new feature was added that I missed or PyCharm works differently than IntelliJ.

Comment: @JulesOlléon In IntelliJ 2021.1.1, I see a Shell Script run config type. It has one option to choose between a script file or script text. For the script file, you can select the script path and enter environment variables. For the script text, I assume you can write a command directly such as in my answer.

Comment: That's what I was expecting to find somewhere but unfortunately, looks like these options didn't make it to PyCharm! In PyCharm the Shell Script run config only allows you to pick a "Script path", "Interpreter path", and script and interpreter options but no room for environment variables (I tried to put variables in the options sections or prepend to script paths but none of this works). What a weird omission, right?... that's why I feel like I must be missing something...

Comment: @JulesOlléon Will you add a screenshot to your OP?

Comment: yep, just did :)

Comment: @JulesOlléon And whate version of PyCharm is this? In IntelliJ 2021.1.1 I have an Environment Variables field immediately below Working Directory and before Interpreter.

Comment: PyCharm 2019.3.4 (Community Edition)
macOS 10.14.6

Comment: @JulesOlléon This looks like a bug in the Shell Scripts run config dialog. I suggest you update to 2021.1 to see if this is fixed.

Comment: Yes!! After updating to the latest version (2021.1.1), this added an "Environment Variables" box on the config panel. It's all working as expected now. Thank you @Code-Apprentice !